# ActiveMQ with more than one Listener

Tags: spring, listener, activemq-classic

I am using it with spring. Now I have the following setting:

```
   <!--异步调用消息 -->
<bean class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cacheConnectionFactory"></property>
    <!-- <property name="destination" ref="ptpQueue"></property> -->
    <property name="destination" ref="topicQueue"></property>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="objHelper"></property>
    <property name="sessionAcknowledgeModeName" value="AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE"/>
</bean>
```

My `messageListener` only listens `ref="objHelper"` but now I want it to listen on both `ref="objHelper"` and `ref="bexHelper"` !

Both my `objHelper` and `bexHelper` have implemented `MessageListener` and have a method `onMessage(){………… }` but I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The Spring MessageListenerContainer can only be configured with exactly one message listener.
So this is not possible.

Why do you need to use 2 message listeners on the same message listener container?